# Keep running NSOperationQueue when app goes to background

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm downloading files using `NSOperation` (s) and adding them `NSOperationQueue`. `NSOperationQueue` is getting suspended when app goes in the background. Is there any work around if queue will not suspend in the background and start the next operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your queue is running use the `UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` call to start a background task that will keep your downloads running.

I generally wrap up each operation with its own `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` call, and queue the next one up before I call `endBackgroundTask` that way the queue keeps running.

*note* an individual background task is limited to 10 minutes of operation, after that iOS will suspend the app.

Comment: I realize this comment was several years ago, but I'm curious how you implemented this. Do you call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` inside of the NSOperation subclass?

Comment: -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [application endBackgroundTask:task];
    task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];}

Answer (score 0):

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

```
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:task];
        task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
```

}